# Why matlab can not compute this integral?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate this integral, but the minus one at the bottom is causing some errors.

```
Kb=1.381e-23; %J/k
h=6.626e-34; %J*s
Ts=5760; %k
Tc=300; %k
q=1.60e-19; %J
c=3.0e8; %m/s
theta_s=atan(7e8/1.5e11) %rad
theta_e=pi/2;
theta_x=4.66e-3
syms E;

Eg=1.3*1.602e-19;

Il = int(E^2/((exp(E/Kb/Ts)-1)),E,Eg,Inf)
eval(Il)
```

I get the follow error when I try to run the code.

```
Error using evalin
Undefined function 'polylog' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

Error in sym/eval (line 11)
s = evalin('caller',vectorize(map2mat(char(x))));

Error in homework3_stackoverflow_help (line 15)
eval(Il)
```

If I have the `exp(E/Kb/Ts)-1` at the bottom it will give me error. However when I remove the one. `exp(E/Kb/Ts)` works just fine. The integral can be found here http://pveducation.org/pvcdrom/solar-cell-operation/detailed-balance

Comment: General rule: wolfram alpha is usually your best bet for solving an integral

Comment: this is what wolfram gave me http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=x%5E2%2F%28%28exp%28x%2F%28a*b%29%29-1%29%29&random=false what is the `Li`?

Comment: I'm not sure that integral has a closed form solution. Matlab is just giving you an equivalent version as a limit. Mathematica 9 also refuses to solve it. Removing the `-1` is only valid if the other part is significantly larger than one over the entire bounds of the the integral (and yes, in that case there are [easy closed form solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions)). But why are you trying to solve this symbolically in the first place? And working with small values is not idea either -you might look into scaling the units in your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by `But why are you trying to solve this symbolically in the first place?` I need `syms E` or else Matlab will give me an error. Or are you asking about the `E` in the integral? If I replace `int(E^2/((exp(E/Kb/Ts)-1)),E,Eg,Inf)` with `int(E^2/((exp(E/Kb/Ts)-1)),Eg,Inf)` I get the same answer.

Comment: Of course you have to define `E` as symbolic if you're using the symbolic function `int`. What I mean is why aren't you using numerical quadrature (e.g., `quadgk`, `integral`, etc.) as opposed to symbolic math?